# How can I check if a file exists on a remote server using Perl?

Tags: perl, ftp, module

How can I check if a file exists on a  remote server using Perl?

Can I do this while using the Perl module `Net::FTP`?

**CHECK TO SEE IF FILE EXISTS**

```
if (-e $file_check) {  
    print "File Exists!\n";  
}   
else {  
    print "File Doesn't Exist!\n";  
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You might be best served by using SSH to do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $ssh  = "/usr/bin/ssh";
my $host = "localhost";
my $test = "/usr/bin/test";
my $file = shift;

system $ssh, $host, $test, "-e", $file;
my $rc = $? >> 8;
if ($rc) {
    print "file $file doesn't exist on $host\n";
} else {
    print "file $file exists on $host\n";
}
```

Comment: but what to do, if its a remote server which is password protected?

Comment: @Jithin That is what ssh keys are for.

Comment: Yeah, I got it. But is there any workaround in the script, if the remote server is password protected?

Comment: @Jithin Yes, you could try using [Net::SSH::Expect](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-SSH-Expect/lib/Net/SSH/Expect.pod), but that way madness lies.  All properly configured machines will accept keys and they are much more secure.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Just got curious that, the passwords can given using the system command itself without using any module.. ;-)

Comment: @Jithin The `ssh` command line program is designed to not allow that (due to security issues).

Answer (score 4):

You could use a command such as:

```
use Net::FTP;
$ftp->new(url);
$ftp->login(usr,pass);

$directoryToCheck = "foo";

unless ($ftp->cwd($directoryToCheck))
{
   print "Directory doesn't exist
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the file is in the FTP space on the remote server, then use Net::FTP.  Get an `ls` listing of the directory and see if your file is in there.

But you can't just go and see if any arbitrary file is on the server.  Think of what a security problem that would be.

Answer (score 1):

Log in to the FTP server, and see if you can get an FTP `SIZE` on the file you care about:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::FTP;
use URI;

# ftp_file_exists('ftp://host/path')
#
# Return true if FTP URI points to an accessible, plain file.
# (May die on error, return false on inaccessible files, doesn't handle
# directories, and has hardcoded credentials.)
#
sub ftp_file_exists {
    my $uri = URI->new(shift); # Parse ftp:// into URI object

    my $ftp = Net::FTP->new($uri->host) or die "Connection error($uri): $@";
    $ftp->login('anonymous', 'anon@ftp.invalid') or die "Login error", $ftp->message;
    my $exists = defined $ftp->size($uri->path);
    $ftp->quit;

    return $exists;
}

for my $uri (@ARGV) {
    print "$uri: ", (ftp_file_exists($uri) ? "yes" : "no"), "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an expect script for the same purpose (requires no extra modules). The expect will execute "ls -l" on the FTP server and the perl script will parse the output and decide if file exists. Its really simple to implement.

Here's the code,

PERL script: (main.pl)

```
# ftpLog variable stores output of the expect script which logs in to FTP server and runs "ls -l" command
$fileName = "myFile.txt";
$ftpLog = `/usr/local/bin/expect /path/to/expect_script/ftp_chk.exp $ftpIP $ftpUser $ftpPass $ftpPath`;

# verify that file exists on FTP server by looking for filename in "ls -l" output
if(index($ftpLog,$fileName) > -1)
{
    print "File exists!";
}
else
{
    print "File does not exist.";
}
```

EXPECT script: (ftp_chk.exp)

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set force_conservative 0;
set timeout 30
set ftpIP [lindex $argv 0]
set ftpUser [lindex $argv 1]
set ftpPass [lindex $argv 2]
set ftpPath [lindex $argv 3]

spawn ftp $ftpIP

expect "Name ("
send "$ftpUser\r"

sleep 2

expect {
"assword:" {
    send "$ftpPass\r"
    sleep 2

    expect "ftp>"
    send "cd $ftpPath\r\n"
    sleep 2

    expect "ftp>"
    send "ls -l\r\n"
    sleep 2

    exit
    }
"yes/no)?" {
    send "yes\r"
    sleep 2
    exp_continue
    }
timeout {
    puts "\nError: ftp timed out.\n"
    exit
    }
}
```

I have used this setup in one of my tools and I can guarantee that it works perfectly :)